# Fastest way to find dividers of a number in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to do an exercise in which you should find number of dividers of factorial of nth number:

https://www.e-olymp.com/en/problems/124

So here is my code:

```
int fact(int n){
    return (n==1 || n==0) ? 1 : n*fact(n-1);
}
long long int a,b=1,c=0;
    cin>>a;
    long long int y=fact(a);
    while(b!=y){
        if(y%b==0){
                c++;
        }
        b++;
    }
        cout<<c+1<<endl;
```

But this code takes too much time and I need something quicker. Don't give code, algorithm will be enough.

Comment: @user2296177 isn't recursive  shorter and faster?

Comment: To count the divisors, you don't need to enumerate them. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1309948/total-number-of-divisors-of-factorial-of-a-number

Comment: Non-recursive approaches are usually faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this task `1 <= N <= 45`. Obviously, `N` is too large to calculate it directly.

You should implement another approach. Just iterate from the `1` to `N` and do the prime factorization for every `i, 1 < i <= N`. Then you can easily find the prime factorization of `N!`, just merge factorization of every `i, 1 < i <= N`. After that calculate the total number of divisors using previously calculated factorization.

Example for 6!:

```
2 = 2
3 = 3
4 = 2 ^ 2
5 = 5
6 = 3 * 2
```

So:

```
6! = 2 ^ 4 * 3 ^ 2 * 5
```

And the number of divisors:

```
(4 + 1) * (2 + 1) * (1 + 1) = 30
```

Comment: What is the formula for fiding factoization of `N!`

Comment: Use your brain. N! is a product, that's the factorisation mostly done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use a bit of mathematics.

If you know the prime factors of a number, it is trivial to calculate the number of divisors.

And it's easy to find the prime factors of a factorial. Without calculating the factorial itself.